# Django complex query

Tags: python, django

I have this UserLink model that basically describes the strength of the relationship between users. The UserLink's weigth gets bigger and increases as the users involved interact in some activities.

```
class UserLink(models.Model):

from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='following_set')
to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='follower_set')
date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
weight = models.FloatField(default=1.0, blank=True, null=True)
active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

There is a function to compute the weight for each pair of users. The problem is I don't know how to create a query thet would return the queryset with the users with the strongest userlink weigth for a selected user, i.e. for the user "Paul" get his "top friends" based on the weigth of the UserLink between Paul and all the others, in descending order.

Answer (score 2):

```
UserLink.objects.filter(from_user=paul).order_by('-weight')
```

And get the `to_user` property from the queryset. If you want to reduce it to a number of users, use `[:5]`. If you want to restrict the query to links with weight over a certain value, use `.filter(from_user=paul, weight__gte=value)`.

I hope this is pretty straightforward and does not need further explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function to compute the weight at the database level, you can use the [extra method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra).

Comment: I dont know what you mean by "database level". I can compute the strength of the link by using a function involving two users. The problem is to create a query that would, the way I see it:
a) get a queryset containing all "friends", users that are linked with the user in question
b) insert somehow the additional "attribute" in the queryset: the link strength
Maybe I'm getting this all the wrong way, I don't know.

Comment: In 'at database level' I mean 'stored procedure inside the database' - performance-wise its the best option.